# Is it possible to get the Google Alerts as structured data?

Tags: google, api, data, monitoring

With the [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts?hl=en) one can subscribe notifications about the newest search results to a given search terms. The alerts are sent to the email. Now, I'd like to analyse this data.

Is there an API for it? (How) Can I get this data as JSON or in an other structured form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Alerts allows you to setup an RSS feed for the alert delivery. That'll probably be your best bet to get the data in a structured form.

Comment: Google News also allows for custom searches to have RSS feeds but not all.

Comment: Oh, sure -- an RSS feed is an XML document, that means it's structured data and easy to parse. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[This artictle](http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/09/11/google-alerts-regains-rss-delivery-option-it-lost-after-google-readers-demise/) has good instructions for getting Google Alerts RSS feeds:

> To use the feature, log in to your Google Alerts account and make sure you have at least one entry. If you don’t, create one by picking a search query for Google to track for you.
>
> Next, click on [Manage Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts/manage) and hit the Edit button on an alert you want to get an RSS feed for. Under the “Deliver to” option, change the option from your email address to “Feed.” Hit the blue Save button.
>
> The Feed option will change to an RSS link, which you can then copy and paste into your favorite RSS reader. For example, Google generates [this one](http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/02238178350374140863/295925814457460937) for the query “The Next Web.”